# How to view log of Cron Job made by Firebase Cloud Functions?

Tags: firebase, cron, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-scheduler

I have a simple snippet to create cron job using Firebase Cloud Functions:

```
exports.cron = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 1 minute').onRun(async (context) => {

    let date = new Date();
    let dateString = date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes() + ':' + date.getSeconds();
    console.log(`This function was running at ${dateString}`);

    return null;

});
```

However, when I check on the log from Firebase Console > Cloud Functions > Cron, I don't see any message from `console.log()` that I usually see when I use `console.log()` under other Firebase Cloud functions.

I attempted to navigate to [Google Cloud Scheduler Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/), but I don't see any log either, except for the logs that look like this:

```
2020-03-21 00:03:13.911 PDT Cloud Functions CreateFunction us-central1:cron emailgoeshere@gmail.com {"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.Au...
```

It looks like the cron never runs. Is there any way to check if it is actually running? Where can I find the log for console.log() within the cron function as described above?

Comment: GCP's dashboard

Comment: Hi, @ShivamSingh, where exactly can I find that?

Comment: you will have to select the correct project in GCP & it shall be their upfront on the dashboard with a graph (heading API) in the second column.

Comment: if you cannot find the API graph upfront on the dashboard, on the right corner, there is a `customise` button, you can enable to show the graph from there.

Comment: Below the graph, there is a button `go-to API overview`, where you can see listed all type s of APIs including cloud functions, click on them --> `view metrics` for details regarding traffic/error/latency etc in graph view with the timestamp

Comment: To be able to run Schedule Functions you must be on the Blaze billing plan. Are you on this plan or you are on the free Spark one?

Comment: If you successfully deploy the function, but it doesn't seem to run at all, please contact Firebase support directly. https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact

Comment: @Doug Stevenson: Hi. Is there any way I can know for sure the cron doesn't run before I contact support? Like, I would like to know where the console.log() output to to check first, but I am not sure where to check.

Comment: Support will help you figure that out if you're not already doing that correctly.  Be sure to explain what you're doing.